# split off function for variable as separator

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex

How/Possible to change this implementation of `\xSplit` so that the separator is a
variable filled in at the time of definition (`\edef` somehow?) or at the actual use of
the command??

```
%based on the following code
%TeX by Topic unknown number of arguments p105
%\White(K1a,Q2b,3c,P4d)%

\def\endpiece{xxx}% a sentinel that ends the lists of inputs 
\def\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece#1{*#1}
```

something simple to illustrate: putting a star in front of it

```
\def\sep{,}
```

I would like to use this inside the definition of `\xSplit` like `\def\xSplit#1\sep{...}`
where `\sep` is the separator between parts: a comma for the example below.
I could of course use a function `\xSplitComma` to split of a comma and 
`\xSplitSemicolon`  ... where those separators are hardwired in it but I 
would like it to be a variable so that I have to define
`\xSplit` only once where `\sep` and `\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece` are defined 
according to my wishes
extra question: would it be possible to redefine `\sep` 
inside `\dosomethingwithsplitpiece` so that `\xSplit`
splits off on `;` for example instead of `,` after for example a 
certain amount of , are found
or recursively where first is split of by comma and those chunks as a result 
are split off by semicolon and so on.

```
\def\xSplit#1,{\def\temp{#1}% replace , by \sep
\ifx\temp\endpiece% no more to process
\else% 
   \dosomethingwithsplitofpiece{#1}%
   \expandafter\xSplit%
\fi%
}%

\def\Split(#1){#1 transforms into \xSplit#1,xxx,% >-- how this comma as a variable 
                                                % that can be changed if necessary??
}%
```

This is a list of numbers seperated by a comma as an example and then a star is
placed in front of the split of chunk each time

```
\Split(4,5,6,7,9,10,11)
 % \Split(4,5,6;7,9,10;11){1} 

\bye
```

Comment: @close-voters: did you read the code and questions embedded? Yes, it'd be better if the question was fully explained in the body of the question, but this post is far from "unclear".

Comment: I've minimised the example a little: the fact that it's a plain TeX application should be clear from `\bye` but I've also tagged as such. Notably, a solution here in TeX macros or using a generic package will be applicable to both plain and LaTeX.

Comment: I take it that you do not need an expandable solution? As with all questions of this type: are we allowed e-TeX/pdfTeX extensions or just TeX90?

Comment: Can it be done without extensions and the most plain tex available (TeX90)?? Assume only the TeXbook and its commands described in it.

Comment: @lampter Yes, of course, just wanted to know what the conditions were (some things are more convenient with the extensions or can be done expandably).

Answer (score 3):

You have to redefine the splitting macro each time, as you don't know what the separator will be at calling time:

```
\def\Split(#1){%
  \makexSplit
  \expandafter\xSplit\expandafter{\sep}{#1}%
}
\def\xSplit#1#2{\xxSplit#2#1\endpiece#1}

\def\makexSplit{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\xxSplit####1\sep}%
  \x{%
    \def\temp{##1}%
    \ifx\temp\endpiece
    \else
      \dosomethingwithsplitofpiece{##1}%
      \expandafter\xxSplit
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\endpiece{\endpiece} % don't use \endpiece in the wild!
\def\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece#1{*#1} 

\def\sep{,}

\Split(4,5,6,7,9,10,11)

\def\sep{;}

\Split(4;5;6;7;9;10;11)

\bye
```

[image]

The only token that can't appear in the list is `\endpiece`. Beware that using it in your document except in this context (or a similar context as a terminator) will lead to infinite loop.

The lines

```
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\xxSplit####1\sep}%
  \x{%
```

might be substituted with

```
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\xxSplit\expandafter##\expandafter1\sep{%
```

if `\sep` is expected to contain tokens that don't survive `\edef`.

---

A higher level solution using `expl3` (but this requires e-TeX):

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_lampter_split_arg_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \Split ( #1 )
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_lampter_split_arg_seq \sep { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_lampter_split_arg_seq
   {
    \dosomethingwithsplitofpiece{##1}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece#1{*#1}

\def\sep{,}

\Split(4,5,6,7,9,10,11)

\def\sep{;}

\Split(4;5;6;7;9;10;11)

\bye
```

The macro `\Split` will use the current value of `\sep` to split the argument at. Then `\seq_map_inline:Nn` takes care of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\declaresplitsep` macro which redefines the `\split` macro with desired separator:

```
\def\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece#1{*#1}

\def\declaresplitsep#1{%
   \def\split(##1){\splitA##1#1#1}%
   \def\splitA##1#1{\ifx#1##1#1\else\dosomethingwithsplitofpiece{##1}\expandafter\splitA\fi}%
}

\declaresplitsep,
\split(4,5,6,7,9,10,11)

\declaresplitsep;
\split(4;5;6;7;9;10;11)

\end
```

This seems to be a little cryptic. So, I show how I wrote this macro. Fist, I defined the `\split` with concrete separator (comma):

```
\def\split(#1){\splitA#1,,}%
\def\splitA#1,{\ifx,#1,\else \dosomethingwithsplitofpiece{#1}\expandafter\splitA \fi}
```

Second, I packed this code to the `\def\declaresplitsep#1{...}` and I doubled all `#` marks and finally I replaced comma by `#1`.